# Show Window Progress but not ActionBar Progress (using v7 compat library)

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have seen a few people trying to get an indeterminate progress bar to show and that is kind of the opposite problem than I am having.

What I want is when the app starts to do work the user sees an indeterminate progress bar at the top of the `Window`.  Then goes away when the work is complete.

I am using the app compat v7 library.  My `Activity` extends `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`.

The code I have in my `Activity.onCreate()` is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ...
}
```

Then when work starts (in a Fragment, not on the main thread):

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Then when work completes:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

Two curious behaviors I can't really explain.  First, on `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)` Both the `Window` progress shows (that I want) **and** the Action Bar's circular progress bar shows.

[image: when searching starts]

Second, on `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false)` the `Window` progress hides (hurray) **and** that's it... the circular progress bar stays visible...

[image: when searching completes]

So I don't know why any of the Action Bar's progress stuff happens, nor do I know how to make it stop.  If I knew the `id` of the progress view in the Action Bar I could look that up in the menu and make sure it stays hidden, but I don't know that `id` (also seems like the wrong way to go about that).

Any help explaining this behavior would be great.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue:

It's not obvious from the code given, but the calls to `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` were being called from a background thread.  If I move that code to the UI Thread, everything works without UI glitches.

For the second issue:

It does seem that the default behavior should be to show the circular progress bar on the ActionBar.  Not entirely sure why the progress on the top of the activity shows as well.  You **can** hide the ActionBar's progress with a style, but I moved away from that before I tested it on older Android platforms.